# Is there a way to transform xml in html without the need to follow the xml structure?

Tags: html, xml, templates, transform

I need to transform xml to html. I am using xsl and xsltproc but noticed that I need to know the xml structure in order to generate the right html for it. I want to create the xsl which should be universal for all xml docs, no matter their structure.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

All I want is, for instance, wherever the transformer sees xml tag para to replace it with html tag p and the value of par without keeping in mind the structure of the xml. I need a copy of the xml but in html.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you expect and what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: "wherever the transformer sees xml tag para to replace it with html tag p and the value of par without keeping in mind the structure of the xml" - that's pretty much a description of how XSLT template rules work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a sample XML of...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <para rollno="392">
        <someValue>365 days</someValue>
    </para>
</xml>
```

> All I want is, for instance, wherever the transformer sees xml tag para to replace it with html tag p and the value of par without keeping in mind the structure of the xml.

...you can replace all `para` tags with `p` tags with a simple template. Combine this/these template(s) with the *identity template* and you can replace certain tags independent of the XML structure.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- Create HTML prologue -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Replace 'para' with 'p' -->
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p rollno="392">
      <someValue>365 days</someValue>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```